# Using ssh with wallet on KDE

Tags: ssh, kde

How can I use wallet with ssh keys?

I found many different descriptions, I've got ssh-agent running, I've added a script at `Autostart/ssh-add.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
export SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/bin/ksshaskpass
/usr/bin/ssh-add  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.2
/usr/bin/ssh-add  ~/.ssh/id_rsa.3
```

When KDE started for the first time after adding that, I was asked for a password to unlock wallet, and for the password for unlocking the files. I've checked, the passwords are stored in wallet.

However when I run ssh from command line, then I'm still asked for the password for ssh account.

Any ideas what I could check or change?

Comment: You to export it to the computer your connecting to, it is not enough to just do it on your system...

Comment: Yep, I know. I've already switched from xfce and I used gnome keyring there, and all the keys worked there. I'd like to have it working on KDE as well.

Answer (score 5):

[This post suggests using `kssaskpass`](https://saywebsolutions.com/blog/setup-kde-wallet-for-use-with-ssh-keys): and it worked on my machine™ *(Kubuntu 20.10)*

> 1. Install ksshaskpass *(was already installed for me)*
>
>    `sudo apt install ksshaskpass`
> 2. Create an autostart script *(script content below)*
>
>    `nano ~/.config/autostart-scripts/ksshaskpass.sh`
> 3. Add execute permissions and run the autostart script
>
>    `chmod +x ~/.config/autostart-scripts/ksshaskpass.sh`
>
>    `~/.config/autostart-scripts/ksshaskpass.sh`

I was prompted for all of the SSH key passwords (ticking the 'Remember password for each), and with the KWallet Manager open I could see them being added to the wallet one by one.

Here's my version of `~/.config/autostart-scripts/ksshaskpass.sh`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
  
export SSH_ASKPASS='/usr/bin/ksshaskpass'

# loop through all RSA private keys (change this if you need to)
for i in ~/.ssh/*_rsa; do
        ssh-add $i < /dev/null
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SSH_ASKPASS` to tell ssh what method to use to provide the answer. For example i use keychain for my keys management so I have a script here:

`~/.config/autostart-scripts/ssh-add.sh`

With:

`/usr/bin/keychain --eval --agents ssh --inherit any mykey`

Here `mykey` is the public key. In my case, I find useful to name them.

At next log in, you will have KDE to ask you to unlock the key, and it will be valid for the rest of the session.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I organized connecting to my remote machine with a RSA key:

You may first need to run this -  you can probably skip it as you have a key already - this just creates a key:

```
 ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Answer all the questions it asks -  you can just press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but a password is recommended although I have not tested it with Desktop key wallets.

You then need to export it to the remote machine - you need to specify `USERNAME` and `IP_ADDRESS`:

```
 cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys'
 cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh USERNAME@IP_ADDRESS 'cat >> .ssh/authorized_keys2'
```

Then all you should need to do is test it:

```
 ssh <USERNAME>@<IP_ADDRESS>
```

You should get no password prompt (unless set), and as it seems to work on a machine with **no** Desktop Environments installed, it should also work in KDE [image: smiley]

**N.B.**
And as noted in the comments, `ssh-copy-id` can be used to copy the file.

Comment: This is not an answer as it creates a ssh key without password! This is insecure. 

And by the way to transfer your key to the remote machine, you can use `ssh-copy-id -i rsa.pub user@host`

Comment: @Corni thanks. This answer also appears to be from before I was aware of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172143/do-we-have-a-policy-on-smileys !!